Inverse of the homomorphism $A/\displaystyle \bigcap \mathfrak{a}_i \to \prod A/\mathfrak{a}_i$
I’m reading Lang’s “Algebra” (3rd edition) and came across this result: Let $\mathfrak{a}_1,...,\mathfrak{a}_n$ be ideals of $A$ and assume that $\mathfrak{a}_i+\mathfrak{a}_j=A$ for $i \neq j$. Consider the map $$f:A \to \prod_{i=1}^n A/\mathfrak{a}_i=(A/\mathfrak{a}_1)\times ... \times (A/\mathfrak{a}_n).$$ The kernel of $f$ is $\ker(f)=\displaystyle \bigcap_{i=1}^n \mathfrak{a}_i$ and since $f$ is surjective then $A/\displaystyle\bigcap \mathfrak{a}_i \to \prod A/\mathfrak{a}_i$ is an isomorphism.
Is there any way to find the inverse of $A/\displaystyle \bigcap \mathfrak{a}_i \to \prod A/\mathfrak{a}_i$ explicitly? How can I define the multiplication on $\displaystyle \prod A/\mathfrak{a}_i$?

Please do not use images to convey critical mathematical information not otherwise present in your post.

"this result" is the Chinese Remainder Theorem. There is no simple formula in terms of a tuple, as you can readily see by considering the case of $\mathbb{Z}$ and two coprime ideals.

I find it easier this way, instead of writing the same thing.

I know you do. And did you go see the link to see why, even though you find it easier for you, you still shouldn't do it?

I edited the post.

@PedroMartinez Great. Just to add on what Arturo already wrote / linked to: I use this site mainly on my phone (for reading and commenting). Images are very hard to parse on the phone. Just saying that accessibility is a big topic that is not just beneficial for people with disabilities, but eventually for everyone.

The inverse map (the CRT formula) arises from constructing the associated idempotents using the hypotheses $,{\frak a_i + a_j} =1,\ i\neq j,,$ as described in detail here in the linked dupe. $\ \ $

I expanded the prior linked answer. If anything remains unlcear then you are welcome to ask for elaboration in comments.

Thank you for removing the image.

Yes, the proof of surjectivity provides an inverse. This is a classical case of something that should not be buried in the proof since it may be useful for calculations.
For simplicity, I will only explain the case $n = 2$. The general case is somewhat similar (but not in a straight forward way).
More generally, let $U,V$ be subgroups of an abelian* group $A$ with $U + V = A$. Then the canonical map
$$\alpha : A/(U \cap V) \to A/U \times A/V, \quad [a] \mapsto ([a],[a])$$
is an isomorphism.
Namely, the map is clearly injective. For surjectivity, let $([a_1],[a_2]) \in A/U \times A/V$. By assumption, we can write
$$a_1 = u_1 + v_1, \quad a_2 = u_2 + v_2$$
for some $u_i \in U$, $v_i \in V$. Then $a := v_1 + u_2$ is an element with
$$a \equiv a_1 \bmod U, \quad a \equiv a_2 \bmod V,$$
which precisely means that $[a]$ is a preimage.
Therefore,
$$\varphi : A/U \times A/V \to A/(U \cap V),\quad ([u_1 + v_1],[u_2 + v_2]) \mapsto [v_1 + u_2]$$
is the desired inverse map. It is as constructive as it can get provided you have a constructive evidence for $U + V = A$.
Conversely, assume that $\alpha$ is surjective. Then in particular every element $([a_1],0)$ has a preimage, where $a_1 \in A$. This means there will be some $a \in A$ with $a \equiv a_1 \bmod U$ and $a \equiv 0 \bmod V$. Thus, $a \in V$ and $a-a_1 \in U$. This simplifies to $a_1 \in U + V$. This shows that $U + V = A$ is equivalent to surjectivity of $\alpha$.
*It also works for normal subgroups of a group which is not necessarily abelian.

Thank you! How do you define the product of $[u_1+v_1]$ and $[u_2+v_2]$ in this case (to prove that $\varphi(xy)=\varphi(x)\varphi(y)$)?

These are additive groups. And there is no need to define anything as if it was not defined already. Please look at the definition of quotient groups and quotient rings. $[x] + [y] := [x+y]$. Also, inverses of group (or ring) homomorphisms are always group (or ring) homomorphisms. You don't need to prove that here again in this special case.

Yes, but I need to show that directly (without the fact that the inverse of homomorphisms are homomorphisms).

And in such case, what is the multiplicative unit? I'm so confused with that.
